# Display word count field beside the body

Tags: drupal

I want to limit the number of words a person can enter into a body of a content type.
And show the word count to the user.

What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **easiest solution** would be to install this drupal module:

https://drupal.org/project/maxlength

If you are looking to do this manually you can try this solution:

Add this to your form field definition:

```
    '#attributes' => array('onKeyPress' => "return textareaMaxLength(this, event, $sms_max_len);"),
```

**Add a new JS file to your theme:**

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'). '/myfile.js');
```

**Myfile.js:**
    function textareaMaxLength(field, evt, limit) {
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
      var charCode =
        (typeof evt.which != "undefined") ? evt.which :
       ((typeof evt.keyCode != "undefined") ? evt.keyCode : 0);

```
  if (!(charCode >= 13 && charCode <= 126)) {
    return true;
  }

  return (field.value.length < limit);
}
```

*Credit for script/reference:
https://drupal.org/node/80122*